# Flavor/meaning/nuance of "aliquando" in "tandem aliquando"?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, nuance

The first sentence of Cicero's second Catilinarian reads in part

> Tandem aliquando, Quirites, L. Catilinam . . . ex urbe . . . ejecimus.

(I realize I'm leaving out all the fun parts; forgive me.)

You can't say "Finally at some point, Romans," etc. in English, so I'm trying to figure out what flavor *aliquando* adds to *tandem*.

Yonge translates the part I've quoted as

> At length, O Romans, we have dismissed from the city . . . Lucius Catiline.

and Grant gives

> At long last, citizens, Lucius Catilina . . . has been expelled from Rome.

"At length" seems like a straight translation of *tandem*. I imagine that "at long last" could add to "at last" a flavor of having waited for something a very long time, but I could also just be making that up.

A search of the corpus for *tandem aliquando* shows several occurrences (many in the Catilinarians), but I can't figure out from any of the rest of them what "aliquando" is doing.

What's the difference between *tandem* and *tandem aliquando*?

Comment: The question pushes my English beyond my knowledge, but as far as I understand it, the word *eventually* has both functions at a time: to mark the end of something, and to point that there was an underterminate wait, am I wrong?

Comment: Ah, interesting. You can't say "eventually" about something in the present tense—only past or future—but you could approximate it with something like, "Finally, after God knows how long, we've kicked Catiline out."

Comment: FWIW, my sense of what *aliquando* is doing is the same as Rafael's.

Comment: @JoelDerfner not even in present perfect like in *ejecimus*? I mean, present perfect happens in the past: it is only *from* the present that it is reported

Comment: Hmm. "We have eventually kicked him out" sounds weird to me.

Comment: @Rafael, do you want to turn this into an answer? I feel like it makes a lot of sense, and even if you don't have rock-solid evidence I'm inclined to accept it if nobody else comes along with a more informed opinion.

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a try as soon as I can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Aliquando` (at some point in time) besides `Tandem` (finally) seems to be adding that the -long or eagerly expected- end of a process (expelling LC) was reached after an undeterminate waiting period (thus emphasizing that it felt long).

Comment: I (and [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daliquando)) agree that *tandem* adds an exasperated "finally", e.g. "After all this time--*finally*--etc." Note that this is kind of similar to the beginning of the First Cataline Oration: *usque tandem*